NVM Version Stops Working Randomly - Requires Reinstall To Fix
I have 2 systems that use two different versions of node. For some reason, it will randomly stop using the version I'm on (I.E. When I run 'nvm ls', the * isn't next to any of the versions and running 'nvm use version' doesn't change that), and the only way to get it to work again is to delete the nodejs folder and then uninstall and reinstall the versions I need (Or delete the version folders and reinstall).
I understand from some research that it's a permissions thing that stops nvm from updating the currently in use version folder? But it is using up until it isn't (source: nvm use does not switch node versions).
I know how to get it working again, but I don't know why it's happening and was wondering if anyone with more nodejs / nvm experience could help me figure out what might cause this to drop out?
Thank you
